# Create generic instance with delegate arg

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

I am trying to refactor some code by introducing generics, and I got stuck. I am trying to create a new instance of T, but the trouble is, that T has a delegate argument in the constructor. What I was aiming for was something like this:

```
public delegate IOrders DoStuffDelegate(); 


public class GenericBoss<T> where T:Worker
{

    public void DelegateWork()
    {
        T worker = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new[]{GiveOrders})
        worker.Work();
    }

    public IOrders GiveOrders()
    {
        return new OrderFromTheBoss();
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private readonly DoStuffDelegate _takeOrders;

    public Worker(DoStuffDelegate takeOrders)
    {
        _takeOrders = takeOrders;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        _takeOrders(); 
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, as only **[object]** types are allowed as arguments in the **[Activator]**. I am not allowed to change the constructor, so moving the delegate elsewhere is not possible.

Is there a way out, or is generics not an option here?

Regards, 
Morten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know which delegate you want to convert your method group to. If it's *always* the `DoStuffDelegate`, you can just do this:

```
object[] args = new object[] { new DoStuffDelegate(GiveOrders) };
T worker = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
```

or

```
DoStuffDelegate giveOrders = GiveOrders;
object[] args = new object[] { giveOrders };
T worker = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
```

If the delegate type is different for each `T`, it's harder - you'd probably need to call `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create an instance of the appropriate delegate type, discovered via reflection :(

Comment: I think `Activator.CreateInstance` returns an object in this case? An `as` cast or the generic version should be applied.

Comment: @Danny: Yes, the cast would be required - will add that in. I was focusing on the arguments side of things, which I think is the OP's original issue :)

Comment: Yes, I had to cast it back to T, but then it worked. Thank you. You just made my code much prettier :o)